# Consider the power series $ f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \log (n) x^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the power series $ f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \log (n) x^n$. The radius of convergence is

(a) $ \ 0 $ ,

(b) $ \infty $

(c) $ 1 $

**Answer:** Let $ a_n=\log (n).$ Then $a_{n+1}=\log(n+1).$  **Now I need help .**

Then $ \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)} <1 $ 
Then $R <1.$

Comment: I think option $ (c) $ is correct

Comment: Use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Take the limit of $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ using L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: $0 < \log n\leqslant n$ eventually, so the radius is positive. Because $\log n$ doesn't go to zero, the radius is at most $1$. Given you know one of those is correct (I presume?) the correct choice is $(c)$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the ratio test. Find $x$ s.t.

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{\log(n+1) x^{n+1}}{\log n \,x^n}\right| < 1 $$

$$ |x| \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}\right| < 1 $$

$$ |x|<1 $$

So your sum converges when $|x|<1$ and subsequently $R=1$.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach: the geometric series is analytic with radius the convergence $1$, and

> **Theorem:** the derivative of an analytic function is also analytic with the same radius of convergence, and it power series representation is the term-by-term derivative of the power series representation of the original function

The above imply that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$ (the derivative of the geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$) have also radius of convergence $1$. And it is easy to see that

$$|\ln(k)x^k|<|kx^{k-1}|,\quad k\in\Bbb N_{>0}$$

when $x\in(-1,1)$. Thus the radius of convergence of your series is, at least, $1$. By last we can see that the series diverges when $x=1$, hence it radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\lim \frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}=\lim \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n+1}}=\lim \frac{n+1}{n}=1$$

Hence, radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>1$ the series clearly diverges.

Let's $0<x<1$. Then for every $n>1$, we have $$x^{n+1}\log(n+1)/ x^{n}\log(n)=x.\log(n+1)/\log(n)$$ and the limit of that expression is $x<1$, so by the Alembert criteria the series converge.

Then the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

First when $x = 1$, it clearly diverges because the terms are increasing. This means that the radius of convergence is no more than 1. This eliminates b.

When $x = 1/4$, we see that our sequence is bounded above by $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (1/2)^n$ which we know converges. Hence the radius of convergence is at least 1/2. This eliminates a.

Hence the answer is c.

Answer (score 0):

*Ratio test* and *equivalents*:
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\sim_\infty\frac nn=1,$$
hence the radius of convergence is $1$.